Emacs on Mac file opening buffer switching behaviour
I am a very happy user of Emacs on Linux, and a far less happy one on Mac.
I can't seem to get one thing right: switching buffers - I can't fathom the behaviour of Emacs on Mac with Ctrl-x b. Looks like it rotates through a number of windows rather than being back-and-forth between two buffers like on Linux.
Emacs 28.1 (9.0) on Sonoma

What is C-x b bound to?

What build of Emacs?  What packages are installed?

There shouldn't be any significant difference between doing this on Linux and Mac.

Unless you have different options set up in your .emacs. If you read the documentation (with C-h k C-x b) you'll see there are some options that control whether it uses the same window or a different window.

@SolarMike I asked the OP to split them. This one here seems to be about behaviour within Emacs, the other about invoking Emacs from macOS.
